# Capture POST response in HTML page

Tags: html, forms, jsp, post

I am sending a form post to a third party and it is returning a page with Success if the action is done. Once I get the success page, I need to redirect user to a Thank You page. Can somebody tell me how the see if the success page is returned and redirect to another page?

```
<form name="abc"  method="POST" action="third party url" >
    <input />
    <input />
</form>
```

Comment: can you post some code? what does the response look like? is it a Json? are you using jQuery? and what have ou tried?

Comment: the response is an html page. i tried using Ajax, but as the response is html page, that doesn't work for me.

Comment: can you post someof your javascript code? you might need Jsonp

Comment: the code goes like this:

Comment: <form name="abc"  method="POST" action="third party url" >
<input/>
<input/>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

the code goes like this:

```
<form name="abc"  method="POST" action="third party url" >
<input/>
<input/>
</form>
```

but i am not sure how to capture the response

Answer (score 0):

... how about submitting the form and receiving response in an iframe? If you can use an iframe you'll be able to detect the change then.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this easily with plain javascript. When you post a form, the form inputs are sent to the server and your page is refreshed - the data is handled on the server side. That is, the submit() function doesn't actually return anything, it just sends the form data to the server.

If you really wanted to get the response in Javascript (without the page refreshing), then you'll need to use AJAX, and when you start talking about using AJAX, you'll need to use a library. jQuery is by far the most popular, and my personal favourite. There's a great plugin for jQuery called Form which will do exactly what it sounds like you want.

Comment: You might want to use a library to make `AJAX` requests but it isn't *necessary*. Keep in mind that jQuery itself is just written in JavaScript.